# Linear homeomorphism and supremums (is this right?)

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $F:Y \to X$ be a linear homeomorphism between Banach spaces.  So $x \in X$ iff $Tx \in Y$ and $F$ and its inverse are continuous.

Suppose $G:X \to \mathbb{R}$.
Is it true that
$$\sup_{y \in Y}\frac{|G(F(y))|}{|y|_Y} = \sup_{x \in X}\frac{|G(x)|}{|F^{-1}(x)|_Y}$$

This is probably a stupid question but I just want to check. I think it is true because the spaces are isomorphic so it doesn't matter which we take supremums over as long as adjust the expression. I am worried that I can't do this because there may be uncountably infinite elements in the space or something like that.

Comment: Yes, it is true and even bijection is sufficient.

Comment: You need to exclude $0$ from the sets you take the $\sup$ over to avoid dividing by $0$. But then the two are equal, since you can write every $x$ as $F(y)$ in a unique way.